# Spark and Kafka integration - KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm working on an integration project of Kafka and Spark and I'm trying to read a Kafka topic using Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.12.11 and Kafka 2.5.0.

My sbt file is:

```
name := "Test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.11"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12" % "2.4.5",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12" % "2.4.5",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12" % "2.4.5",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.5.0"
)
```

my code is:

```
object Test{
def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    val spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("SparkTest")
              .master("local[*]")
              .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = spark.readStream
             .format("kafka")
             .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
             .option("subscribe", "test")
             .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
             .load()

    df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
           .as[(String, String)]

    df.printSchema()
}}
```

After having created the topic on Kafka, started zookeeper and Kafka itself, when I launch the code with:

```
./spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.5 --class Test /home/luca/Projects/Test/target/scala-2.12/test_2.12-1.0.jar
```

I run into the following error:

```
    20/05/06 15:40:29 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
    at Test$.main(projectfile.scala:24)
    at Test.main(projectfile.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 26 more
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka- client version can be one of the reasons. Otherwise, try with spark 2.4.0 and scala 2.12 earlier versions. Looks like a compatibility issue